# iOS App Store: Can't scroll to see more results

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

When searching with a keyword in the App Store app on my iPhone, I unable to scroll to see more results. What could be causing the issue? I am running iOS 12.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To resolve, try the following one by one:

1. Relaunch the App Store app. Invoke the multitasking UI by double pressing Home button, and swipe up to quit the app. Now relaunch the app and try again.

   [image]
2. Make sure you have an active Internet connection and the App Store is able to access it. You can browse around in the app to ensure you have an active connection.
3. Try connecting to a different Wi-Fi/mobile data network (basically to a different ISP). Sometimes App Store may not be able to fetch data over some network. Switching to a different network may help resolve the issue.
4. You can also try by restarting your iPhone.
5. One last resort would be reset your Network Settings. Go to Settings app → General → Reset and tap **Reset Network Settings**. Do note to use it with caution as this will reset all network configuration on your device and you'll have to re-add the saved Wi-Fi access points.

   [image]

Comment: All the step i’m have ready trying and follow but all is not working for..

Comment: @շօօ.Յօօ.Կօօ.օօօ How many search results are you able to see? Is it possible that you have scrolled past all the results?

Comment: What i know thats not many app or game show. by result searching. I don’t know everyone is facing same issue or not. I’m still want to know did this is serious or normal. I don’t mind the App Store have limit reached searching

Comment: @շօօ.Յօօ.Կօօ.օօօ How search works in App Store is Apple's trade secret. However, the number of results shown depend on the keyword used, app category and your App Store region.

Comment: really? but i'm also try to test many region like united state. China . United Kingdom still looks same result. did you not facing this issue same like me?